# How to find file names of deleted database in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the LDF and MDF file names of a database which was restored on SQL server but now it has been deleted.

ALready tried Master tables such as restoreHistory, backupset and backupmediafamily.

I don't actually need to restore any data or query anything from the DB. Just need the file names.
I have full access to the SQL Server and know the DB name.

Comment: Was the database "Detached" instead of "Deleted". Otherwise... I can't imagine the ldf and mdf files hanging out on the file system after a delete...

Comment: It was deleted. I don't need the file. Just need to find what its name was.

Comment: Unless you had some auditing of this type of thing prior to the drop of the database I don't think there is much you can do. But I can't comprehend how knowing the names of files that are now deleted would really help you do anything.

Comment: @SeanLange Its for logging purpose.

Comment: Further clarifying the requirements doesn't change the fact that you would need to put in the auditing before you deleted the database. You can't create this information retroactively. Has the server been rebooted since? Might be something in the DMVs...

Comment: The Server hasn't been rebooted.

Comment: If it's not been long since you deleted the files, you might still be able find it in a application that can restore previously permanently deleted files. But like everyone else said, if you need this for logging, you should be doing this **when** you perform the action. It's no good trying to log a task you completed later when you haven't got all the details any more. This seems like a process fault more than anything.